# Why have typescript class options that have been defined remain possibly undefined?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to predefine (static) options for a class:

```
interface Options {
    startTimeLimit?: number;
    throttlePeriod?: number;
    ....
    ....
}
export class Draggable extends DragElement{
    static init(parentId:string, draggables:NodeList, options:Options) {
      Draggable.options = {
        startTimeLimit: 250,
        throttlePeriod: 100,
        ....
        ....
      }
      Object.assign(Draggable.options, options);
      ....
      ....
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

but I get a type error

> 'Draggable.options.startTimeLimit' is possibly 'undefined'

from the use of `startTimeLimit` (and from all the other uses of these options):

```
var now = e.timeStamp;
if (now - Draggable.lastStartDragTime  < Draggable.options.startTimeLimit) {
    // debounce
    return false;
}
```

As I understand it, the `?` operator makes it possible for the user to provide the options or not, but as I have provided defaults why am I getting this error?

### Edit

After thinking through @johnrsharpe's comment, I see now that TS won't know if `init` has ever been called so cannot know if the variables have been defined. Hence the transpile error.
But that still leaves me wondering how to acheive what I want - i.e. to allow the various options to be unprovided by clients.

Since I *know* that `init()` will always be called (the library can't be used otherwise) is it OK to just use the `!` operator for these varibales?

Comment: Because the type is still fundamentally `number | undefined`. You're accessing the value via the `Options` interface; by allowing it to not be provided, you also have to deal with that possibility in every consumer.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks. I have edited my question - maybe you can help now with an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Draggable.options` is always fully initialized (regardless of the options the user supplies), you can have *its* type not include the `undefined` and then have the user pass a [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) of that. For instance, you might write

```
interface Options {
    // Note: Everything is required
    startTimeLimit: number;
    throttlePeriod: number;
}
```

Then define the static field `Draggable.options` to have type `Options` (so everything is fully present and defined). Then the signature of your function can be

```
static init(parentId: string, draggables: NodeList, options: Partial<Options>)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had been thinking that there _must_ be a way to to this. I have got rid of those 'cheating' `!` operators now :)

Comment: ....and by adding `?` to the options parameter , clients can just call `init()` with the id and the nodelist, if they just want all default options.

Comment: If you add `?` to the options parameter, you may need to do a check for `undefined` inside your function (unless `Object.assign` accepts `undefined`, which I wouldn't be surprised about). But yes, that should work.